# Bootstrap - Getting fancy with <fieldset>s

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build an interface with Bootstrap 3 which looks like this:

```
--------Fieldset--------        -----Fieldset-----
Col 1        Col 2              Some data
Some data    Some data          Some data
Some data    Some data          Some data
Some data    Some data          Some data

------------------------Fieldset------------------------
Some large <textarea>
```

I am not sure how to go about accomplishing this, though. My concerns are the multiple columns in one fieldset, and the bottom fieldset spanning the length of the two fieldsets above it. I know to make stacked fieldsets all I need to do is nest them, but that then restricts the length of the children fieldsets.

Is what I'm doing even possible? Is it going to get ugly like I feel like it will?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Keep breaking it down. You have 2 Field sets next to each other in the outermost layer. So right there you know you need 2 columns.
Then, within the first (left) column, you need 2 more nested columns.
Within the right column you don't need to nest anything.
Then comes the next 'row' that will span the width of your outter two columns.
It's totally possible. Might have a lot of markup though.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://www.bootply.com/rLkFaCBtpK)

Comment: Bootply is inaccessible for me :/

Comment: I provided a better example. This should get you started. From there, it will be up to you to decide how the layout should work for the different sizes (xs, sm, md etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have provided this anyway - sorry about that. Here's some markup that (should) get you rolling.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="mycol-1">
    <p>Fieldset</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Col 1</p>
            <p>Some data</p>
            <p>Some data</p>
            <p>Some data</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Col 2</p>
            <p>Some data</p>
            <p>Some data</p>
            <p>Some data</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="mycol-2">
    <p>Fieldset</p>
    <p>Some data</p>
    <p>Some data</p>
    <p>Some data</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="mycol-3">
    <p>Fieldset</p>
    <p>Some large textarea</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mycol-1 { background-color: red; }
.mycol-2 { background-color: pink; }
.mycol-3 { background-color: orange; }
```

I only used the css as a way to show the boundires. You will probably want to at least rename the classes (or delete them all together). Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome yup this got me going!